# Calculating the bearing between two vectors then diff that against a passed angle

Tags: c++, math, angle

I am trying to find the 2D vector in a set that is closest to the provided angle from another vector.

So if I have `v(10, 10)` and I would like to find the closest other vector along an angle of 90 degrees it should find `v(20, 10)`, for example. I have written a method that I think returns the correct bearing between two vectors.

```
float getBearing(
    const sf::Vector2f& a, const sf::Vector2f& b)
{
    float degs = atan2f(b.y - a.y, b.x - a.x) * (180 / M_PI);
    return (degs > 0.0f ? degs : (360.0f + degs)) + 90.0f;
}
```

This seems to work okay although if I place one above another it returns 180, which is fine, and 360, which is just odd. Shouldn't it return 0 if it is directly above it? The best way to do that would be to check for 360 and return 0 I guess.

My problem is that I can't work out the difference between the passed angle, 90 degrees for example, and the one returned from `getBearing`. I'm not even sure if the returned bearing is correct in all situations.

Can anyone help correct any glaringly obvious mistakes in my bearing method and suggest a way to get the difference between two bearings? I have been hunting through the internet but there are so many ways to do it, most of which are shown in other languages.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the range of the return value? -180 deg to 180 deg or 0 deg to 360 deg? Why are you adding 90 degrees?

Comment: I think I have worked out the diff now, I will post that in a second, but it returns 0-360. I have no idea why I have to add 90, but without it everything is shifted round 90 degrees. Almost as if it is always starting from the west, rather than the north like a bearing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to take the two vectors that are being compared and do an unit dot product. The closest bearing should be greatest, 1 being the maximum (meaning the vectors are pointing to the same direction) and -1 being the minimum (meaning the vectors are pointing to opposite directions).

Comment: +1 although, if only the angle is important (and not its orientation), the relevant quantity is the absolute value of such dot product.

Comment: I agree that this is a better solution for finding the bearing between the vectors. I have added [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14043083/455137) which shows how I worked out the difference between the bearing and an arbitrary angle. Could I use a similar solution on something from the dot product method?

Comment: Since a·b = |a||b|cos(theta) where theta is the angle between the two vectors, you can find such angle by calculating the arccosine of the dot product of the two normalized vectors (theta=arccos((a·b)/(|a||b|))).

Answer (score 3):

If what you need is just to find the vectors nearest to a certain angle, you can follow @swtdrgn method; if, instead, you actually need to compute the angle difference between two vectors, you can exploit a simple property of the dot product:

[image: dot product geometric definition]

where theta is the angle between the two vectors; thus, inverting the formula, you get:

[image: inverse of the formula above]

Comment: This seems very promising, I am having trouble understanding the actual formula though. I understand the use of `acos` and the dot product but I have no idea what the arrows or double pipes (`|a|`) symbolize. Could you possibly write the expression in some kind of pseudo code? I will investigate some of these symbols now anyway, I have just never learnt them. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The arrows mean that a and b are vectors; the "pipes" mean euclidean norm (i.e. the square root of the dot product with itself, i.e. the magnitude of the vector, i.e. that before the dot product a and b have to be normalized). But again, if all you have to do is to find the vector that is nearest to an angle @swtdrgn's solution is the simplest (more straightforward, less calculations) and all in all the best.

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for explaining that. I should really learn this so all those Wikipedia pages will actually be useful to me. I will give the simpler solution a go first and report back here in a minute with an accepted answer. Regardless, thank you for your help.

Comment: @Olical: if you have to work often with vectors you should really read an introductory book on linear algebra, much of this stuff will become obvious. Also, a quick revision of trigonometry won't hurt. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution for now. I have spent a good few hours trying to solve this and I finally do it minutes after asking SO, typical. There may be a much better way of doing this, so I am still open to suggestions from other answers.

I am still using my bearing method from the question at the moment, which will always return a value between 0 and 360. I then get the difference between the returned value and a specified angle like so.

```
fabs(fmodf(getBearing(vectorA, vectorB) + 180 - angle, 360) - 180);
```

This will return a positive float that measures the distance in degrees between the bearing between two vectors. [@swtdrgn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14043006/455137) suggests using the dot product of the two vectors, this may be much simpler than my bearing method because I don't actually need the angle, I just need the difference.

Comment: atan2f(b.y - a.y, b.x - a.x) is not the actual angle between the two vectors... if that's what getBearing suppose to do.

Comment: `getBearing` was supposed to return the degrees from 0 (north) to face the other vector. I thought it was returning the correct values when I was logging it. Is this not the case then? Because it *seems* to be working at the moment.

Comment: **That**, will be where I'm going wrong. Or one of the places anyway. I will commit what I have already which is a bit nasty and try implementing a suggestion from here. I will accept the one I get working that seems the best. Thank you for your help.